# Windows 7 how to remove program

Tags: windows-7, windows

How can I remove the program that starts with http://istart.webssearches.com/  from my PC with Windows7 ?

I cannot remove it in a normal way.

Comment: Your definition of normal way may differ from others. ***What have you tried so far?***

Answer (score 1):

This really could be answered as just sort of a general **How to remove malware X**...

The good news, as this is "malware" of the new variety that plays like legit software and is easy to remove.

If we Google (or Bing, or Yahoo, or DuckDuckGo) "Remove istart" it looks pretty straight foward:

Launch the Add/ remove programs wizard (Start -> appwiz.cpl)

Find:
WPMxxxxxxxx (I used x's where the programs version number appears to be to keep this relevent).

Also, comb the appwiz while you are there for:

- Websearches

And anything else that advertises itself as a search enhancer, coupon clipper or rewards program.

That should be it, although you might have to manually reset all your browsers home pages to your home pages.

Answer (score 0):

We use [Malwarebytes](https://www.malwarebytes.org/mwb-download/) at work to get rid of malware. Give it a try, it is free.